# Query with Regex Replace for Crypto Cleanup

Tags: google-sheets

I have some crypto transactions I am trying to cleanup. The numerical data often has a leading character like this '**Ξ0.001**'.  I'm trying to remove these characters so I can run operations.  I have a working function:

`=QUERY(iferror(ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A1:D4,"^[^0-9]",""))),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4",1)`

The issue is I only want to apply the REGEX to **only columns C and D**. But I need the entire range for my query.  I tried using just C1:D4 but I can't call columns A and B in the subsequent QUERY piece of the function.

Here is the public Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQDKTN7sZObFr0VbsP5zhZPhcl7TWp5Shdr4_2KcyIQ/edit#gid=1458607265

Comment: can you share your import formula?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D4),,9)), 
 "[^A-Za-z -/0-9\.]", ), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: very nice.  So you basically get everything into one cell with the flatten/query/transpose, run the regex, and then split it on space? thanks

Comment: @moonshot yes, exactly